# Calculating a huge fibonacci number modulo m in Python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, fibonacci

The goal of this problem is to calculate **F[n] mod m**. Here the inputs are **n** and **m**, where **n** stands for the index of the fibonacci number, say F[0] = 0, F[1] = 1, F[2] = 1, F[3]= 2 and **m** stands for the number by which **F[n]** will be divided. The constraints are:

- n >= 1 and n <= 10^18
- m >= 2 and m <= 10^5

I have gone this problem so far and been able to generate the exact output of this problem except when I give 100000 as the value of **m**, it exceeds the time limit. The time limit is 5 seconds. If the value of **m** is given between and including from 2 to 99999, my program generates the correct output within the time limit. Any kind of help solving this problem would be highly appreciated.

### Code:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if ( n == 0 ):
        return (0, 1)
    else:
        a, b = fibonacci(n/2)
        c = a * (2* b - a)
        d = a**2 + b**2
        if ( n % 2 ):
            return (d, c + d)
        else:
            return (c, d)


def findRemainders(m):
    remainderList = ["0", "1"]
    i = 2
    while(1):
        firstFib, secondFib = fibonacci(i)
        if ( (firstFib % m) == 0 and (secondFib % m) == 1 ):
            break
        remainderList.append( (firstFib % m) )
        remainderList.append( (secondFib % m) )
        i += 2

    return remainderList


def hugeFibonacciNumberModulo_m( n, m ):
    remainderList = findRemainders(m)
    length_of_period = len(remainderList)
    remainder = (n % length_of_period)
    out = remainderList[remainder]
    return out


inp = map(int, raw_input().split())
n, m = inp[0], inp[1]

if ( (n >= 1 and n <= 10**18) and (m >= 2 and m <= 10**5) ):
    out = hugeFibonacciNumberModulo_m( n, m )
print out
```

Comment: How comes that this problem statement looks so literally familiar? ;-)

Comment: It's very familiar for adepts of competitive programming: It's the FIB64 problem of www.spoj.com
There is 500000 fib(n)%m testcases to solve in less than 2 seconds on a intel G860 CPU arch=skylake with g++ version 8.3.0 (C++14 compliant) n and m are as large as 64bits that is 10^18
It's a good challenge for modular mathematics implementation at the limit of the overflow of the long long int in g++ on intel.
In python the overflow is not a problem but python is too slow for running the 500000 testcases in time.

Comment: My implementation is in C++ and I run all the 500000 testcases in time with this algo of fast doubling but I use a C++ trick to avoid the overflow without implementing a BigInteger library which is far from the goal of the problem.
 NB: external libraries like mpz are forbidden for C++ and even gmpy2 for python

Comment: Another remark: for n=10^15 your memoisation of the terms to find the period of the fib(n)%m is not a good idea as n is big. There is another problem on SPOJ on that math problem: it relates to a math PhD of Michel Renault that is not trivial to implement in C++

Comment: The problem's name on www.spoj.com about fibonacci period is named PISANO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you're attempting to do in `findRemainders(m)` or why you need it. You're already using the Fibonacci-by-doubling algorithm, which is analogous to (and usually derived from) a matrix-exponentiation-by-squaring algorithm. Exponentiation can be modified to efficiently handle modular exponentiation by essentially mod'ing your partial result(s) at each step.

```
def fibmod(n, m):
    assert 1 <= n <= 10**18, n
    assert 2 <= m <= 10**5, m

    def f(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0, 1
        else:
            a, b = f(n // 2)
            c = a * (2*b - a) % m
            d = (a**2 + b**2) % m

            if n % 2 == 0:
                return c, d
            else:
                return d, (c + d) % m

    return f(n)[0]
```

You can break down the expression for `c` and `d` even further and apply `% m` after each intermediate multiplication, addition, and subtraction to prevent overflow (but this isn't really a problem in Python).

Comment: see my comment for the idea of memoisation tried with findReminders. The pattern exist but it involve math far beyound the knowledge of many of us. and the maths in the thesis script are incomplete to implement directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very quickly by using modular exponentiation.

Consider the following matrix multiplication:

```
| 0  1 |     | a |     |  b  |
|      |  x  |   |  =  |     |
| 1  1 |     | b |     | a+b |
```

You should see straight away that the result of this multiplication is the next iteration of the Fibonacci sequence if `a` and `b` are the last two terms. To get the result of performing this multiplication `n` times, you need to calculate the `n-th` power of the 2x2 matrix `(0,1;1,1)` (mod m). This can be done very quickly by raising this matrix to successive powers of 2.

For example, to calculate the 10th power of this matrix:

```
                   | 0  1 |     | 0  1 |     | 1  1 |
A x A  =  A**2  =  |      |  x  |      |  =  |      |
                   | 1  1 |     | 1  1 |     | 1  2 |

                      | 1  1 |     | 1  1 |     | 2  3 |
A**4 =  (A**2)**2  =  |      |  x  |      |  =  |      |
                      | 1  2 |     | 1  2 |     | 3  5 |

                      | 2  3 |     | 2  3 |     | 13  21 |
A**8 =  (A**4)**2  =  |      |  x  |      |  =  |        |
                      | 3  5 |     | 3  5 |     | 21  34 |
```

After squaring the matrix three times, we now have the values of `A**8` and `A**2`. Multiply these together and you get `A**10`:

```
          | 13  21 |     | 1  1 |     | 34  55 |
A**10  =  |        |  x  |      |  =  |        |
          | 21  34 |     | 1  2 |     | 55  89 |
```

These numbers will rapidly become enormous in regular arithmetic, but if you perform all your multiplications modulo m, then this isn't a problem. Finally, multiply the vector (0; 1) by the resulting matrix to get your answer (or, equivalently, just pick out the second number in the top row of the matrix).

The number of multiplications required is of the order of `log(n)`, so the time required should be very small, even if `m` is a trillion or more.

[See Wikipedia for more information about modular exponentiation of matrices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Matrices)

Comment: fast doubling is faster than modular  exponentiatioon