# How can I calculate Fibonacci(A) mod B with A,B<=10^18 in C++ (g++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, g++, implementation

For example, A=10^17, B=10^17 (<64bits) 
Typically, in the algorithm above, the calculs to compute F(2n) and those to compute F(2n+1) exceeds long long int types and we can't use modular computation in it. 
The best algorithm to compute it I talk is fibonacci fast doubling:

> F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1.
>   F(2n) = F(n)(2*F(n+1) – F(n)).
>   F(2n + 1) = F(n)<sup>2</sup> + F(n+1)<sup>2</sup>.

Do you know some types in new C++14 (g++8.3.0 or llvm-clang C++) to use to avoid overflow. 
I tried __float128 that is best than long double with no success. (see the g++ code above)
I have heard of the existence of __int128 and __int256 with no printf possibilities but I haven't try it.
 
Are they availailable in g++ 8.3.0 or are there other fast means to handle 128bits ints to do intermediate calculs you can think of? 
(time perfs are important)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

__float128 a,b,c,d;
long long mod;

void fast_fib(long long n,long long ans[]){
    if(n == 0){
        ans[0] = 0;
        ans[1] = 1;
        return;
    }
    fast_fib((n/2),ans);
    a = ans[0];             /* F(n) */
    b = ans[1];             /* F(n+1) */
    c = 2*b - a;
    if(c < 0) c += mod;
    c = (a * c);      /* F(2n) */
    while(c>=mod)c-=mod;
    d = (a*a + b*b);  /* F(2n + 1) */
    while(d>=mod)d-=mod;
    if(n%2 == 0){
        ans[0] = c;
        ans[1] = d;
    }
    else{
        ans[0] = d;
        ans[1] = c+d;
    }
}

int main(){
  int T=1000;
  long long n;
  while(T--){
    scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&mod);
    long long ans[2]={0};
    fast_fib(n,ans);
    printf("%lld\n", ans[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

with __float128 I can't implement the modulo efficiently and a,b,c,d must store 128 bits data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing numbers with higher precision in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114548/storing-numbers-with-higher-precision-in-c)

Comment: "Fibonnacci(A) exceeds long long int types" -- irrelevant, you only need to compute it modulo B in the first place.

Comment: @harold +1: and then, it's a question for mathoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huge fibonacci modulo m C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679802/huge-fibonacci-modulo-m-c) or you could choose some other algorithm

Comment: Clear explanation (but no code): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556760/calculating-a-huge-fibonacci-number-modulo-m-in-python/40557219#40557219

Comment: @harold: if you have read my question you should have noticed that it's not possible to use modulos in intermediate calculs inside the the algorithm and the scholar fibonacci recursion algorithm is unusable to compute fib(10^18) in reasonable time.

Comment: @YSC: the use of 64bits ints , 128bits ints 128bits float 80bits long double or 256 bits ints is not a question for mathoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any floating point type for the calculations. You can use `long long` type only. First, you need a function that multiplicates two `long long` numbers (that are less than `10^18`) modulo `B`. This can be done with the similar to [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) method:

```
long long multiply(long long a, long long b, long long M) {
    long long res = 0;
    long long d = a;

    while (b > 0) {
        if (b & 1) {
            res = (res + d) % M;
        }
        b /= 2;
        d = (d + d) % M;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Second, you need to add modulo operation to almost all of your arithmetic operations. And you definitely need to replace these loops `while(c>=mod)c-=mod` (they could be very slow) with the addition of `% mod` to the corresponding operations.

Your code with `__float_128` replaced with `long long` and with proper modular arithmetic: https://ideone.com/t6R7Tf

---

Another thing you can do is to use (as was mentioned in the comments) `Boost.Multiprecision` or non-standard `__int128` type (if supported) instead of `long long` type with complicated multiplication.

---

Also, you could use a slightly different (but using the same math actually) approach that seems more obvious to me - the Fibonacci numbers matrix formula

[image]

To calculate the `N`th power of matrix you can use exponentiation by squaring doing all operations modulo `B`.

Comment: It's the same problem as with Fibonacci Fast Doubling algorithm I mention in my post. The problem is more on the types I can use to compute it. I have seen __float128 but I don't think I can implement all int variables with this float one.

Comment: The question mentions g++. Assuming x86_64, `__int128` would make multiplication easier. Or use a Boost.Multiprecision type.

Comment: Note: this is *essentially* the same algorithm as the fast doubling one provided in the question, with the same performance.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, that's right. The earlier version of the question did not contain any code or implementation details, and I proposed the matrix approach that seems to be more obvious to me personally.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368738/552) is another interesting formulation.